# I need a regex to select words from given list of words.

Tags: regex-lookarounds

Ex:

I have list like word1, word2, word3, word4.

I can select one or more words , but only within this four.

Pls tell the regex for this.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found something

^((man1|man2|man3|man4)(,(man1|man2|man3|man4)){0,3})?$

only problem is I cant restrict duplicating.

Any suggestion to restrict duplicating?????